# Issue with Chrome Driver and Chrome binaries

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I decided to have a portable version of chrome along with my chrome driver for my web-scraper in a folder. I then initiate selenium driver and give the binary location as well as driver location to it to initiate a session using

```
`browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)`
```

here are the versions for driver and chrome:

```
Chrome (portable binary) version: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chrome Driver Version: 2.45.615291
```

It gives me this error when I run it:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70825988/18850143)