# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist with chromium browser and Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, selenium-webdriver-python

I want to run selenium through chromium. I wrote this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.binary_location = "/snap/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

But this code throws an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55efd7355a23 <unknown>
#1 0x55efd6e20e18 <unknown>
#2 0x55efd6e46e12 <unknown>
```

The chromedriver of the correct version is in usr/bin. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the chrome driver is in `/usr/bin`, then why are you telling it `/snap/bin/chromium`?

Comment: By default selenium runs google chrome. From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298245/selenium-python-with-chromium-browser-windows, I see that this is how chromium is launched, but I did not find analogues with Linux, in all questions they forward the path to the chromium exe

Comment: There are some similar questions.  It appears to be incompaibility between the ChromeDriver and the actual Chromium instance.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling chromium through apt `sudo apt install chromium-browser` (before that it was installed through snap). My working code looks like this

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
if headless:
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `--headless` argument isn't what fixed it?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 22.04 server. After similar same issues the following worked for me: "const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder('./chromedriver'); const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeService(service).setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments(
 ['--headless','--no-sandbox'])).build();" I systematically went through the other options and when I didn't have the headless and sandbox it broke.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you have specified `--user-data-dir` and maybe a `--profile-directory`, and there is already a running Chrome instance which would have created a `DevToolsActivePort` in your specified user data dir. Thus selenium will be unable to spawn a new browser instance.

My solution is to copy the `Default` and `Profile 1` folders (which are the two profiles I used in my case) under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\` to my newly created `D:\user_data`, and specify `--user-data-dir` to be `D:\user_data`. This way I have a copy of user data for selenium only.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This helped me track down my issue with my script when initially running it, and then having it run as a systemd service.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution here: [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist with chromium browser and Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825917/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-devtoolsa)

In ubuntu, chromium is installed using snap by default, and it breaks selenium.

The following fixed the problem:

```bash
sudo snap remove chromium
```

Then installing the proprietary chrome from https://www.google.com/chrome/

(The official chromium deb package just contains a snap).

Comment: What if you run selenium+docker? I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

### *Thumb rule*

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

However you need to take careof a couple of things:

- [`--disable-gpu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047415/chrome-options-in-python-selenium-disable-gpu-vs-headless/59047724#59047724) was related to [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), so you need to drop it.
- `chrome_options` is deprecated, use *`options`* instead.

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)
- [Selenium-Python with chromium browser (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298245/selenium-python-with-chromium-browser-windows/49301715#49301715)
- [unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error while executing Selenium UI test cases on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790733/unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-error-while-executing-selen/50791503#50791503)

Comment: Although true, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thnx for the feedback, updated the answer, feedback please...

Comment: Is running as `root` also a problem if you have `selenium+docker`?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after upgrading my chromedriver version to 86 and Python runtime to 3.8 from 3.6 on AWS Lambda (Amazon Linux 2) run in a docker container. I played whack a mole for hours with chrome/chromedriver starting issues.

Eventually I found this actively maintained min miplementation of python+selenium+docker. https://github.com/umihico/docker-selenium-lambda/ The setup in their Dockerfile and test.py chrome_options worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on logging helps:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('selenium')
handler = logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

"Headless" was needed to run it as root. However, I had to add "no-sandbox" to get it to run as web-user. No clue why, but this worked for me:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```